Accessing a a non default firestore database from a firebase scheduled cloud function
I have written a cloud function that deploys perfectly well on a schedule, but only for the default database. In our Firebase project, we have a default prod database and a named dev database, and I can't figure out how to talk to the dev database. I am currently using v1, and I know you need to use v2, but I still can't figure out how to change the database, and this version works for at least one database.
when I deploy this:
const functions = require("firebase-functions"); // v1
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

const dbProd = admin.firestore();

const dbDev = admin
  .initializeApp(
    {
      credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
      databaseURL: "https://ourdatabase.firebaseio.com",
    },
    "dbDev"
  )
  .firestore();

and pass it through this function:
exports.updateDevStatusDaily = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every day 00:04")
  .timeZone("America/Denver")
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    await scheduledUpdate(dbDev);
    return null;
  });

it executes the function perfectly, but only on the production database. How can i pass the dev database to my function? Im I using the wrong url?

Add the specific error

There isn't one, it just does its thing to the default  prod database, not the dev database

Well, I gave up and just made two separate Firebase apps. It seems odd that you can have a database you can't address. I still want to know what the answer is.
